# what is the type of super and which class object reference number it contains

Tags: java

what is the type of super keyword and whose reference number it contains?
means super keyword type is super class type or something else and which class reference number it contains means current class object reference or super class object reference ?

```
    class A{}
    class B extends A {    
      public static void main(String s[]){}
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean with `reference number`?

Comment: Try to write in comprehensible English sentences. I would be shocked if anyone would understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`super` is a keyword. It is not an expression or an object and does not have a "type".

You cannot write something like

```
Object x = super;    // no such thing
```

It is a construct to allow you to call methods (and constructors) as implemented by the super class.

Answer (score 0):

super is used to refer immediate parent class instance variable.
    super() is used to invoke immediate parent class constructor.
    super is used to invoke immediate parent class method.

@NARSINGH CHARAN super is always refer to its parent class

Comment: The Object class, which is stored in the java.lang package, is the ultimate superclass of all Java classes (except for Object).